# How to automate the process to open 3 shells and run 3 commands?

Tags: bash, zsh, tmux, emacs

I set up something so that I'd open up 3 shells and run the programs one by one:

```bsh
cd foo/bar
./foo.sh
```

```bsh
cd foo/bar
node bar.js
```

```bsh
cd foo/bar
ruby foobar.rb
```

However, since it is time consuming, so I wrote a shell script to do it:

```bsh
cd foo/bar

./foo.sh &
node bar.js &

ruby foobar.rb
```

However, when I press CTRL-C to stop this script, the other 2 programs are still running.  If I type

```bsh
jobs
```

it won't show the background processes (probably belongs to the script) -- if it did, I could have used `fg` to bring them to the foreground and press CTRL-C on them one by one, so I have to do

```bsh
ps ax | grep foo
ps ax | grep bar
```

to find the process ids and then kill the processes.

Is there a better way to automate the process to open up 3 shells and run 3 programs so that they are like how I open up 3 shells and run them?  I don't care about the STDOUT output, so if one shell window is divided into 3 parts, that's ok.

Can tmux, emacs, or any other tool achieve this goal? (I am not familiar with tmux or emacs enough to know if it is possible).

Comment: Similar: [How to run xfce-terminal with different commands per tab and keep using the tabs after the commands have returned?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/75902)

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer to your main question (I'm a `screen` user myself, never felt the need to move to `tmux`), but a comment on:

> However, since it is time consuming, so I wrote a shell script to do:
>
> ```
> cd foo/bar
>
> ./foo.sh &
> node bar.js &
>
> ruby foobar.rb
> ```
>
> However, when I press CTRL-C to stop this script, the other 2 programs
> are still running

When you do `cmd &` in a non-interactive shell, the shell sets the disposition of the SIGINT and SIGQUIT signals to "ignore" for the process running `cmd` as required by POSIX which explains why <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> doesn't kill them.

However, several shells, including zsh, bash, mksh and yash (but not dash, ksh93, bosh where that `trap` command is ignored) allow you to restore the default disposition for those signals with:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
cd foo/bar || exit
(trap - INT QUIT; ./foo.sh) &
(trap - INT QUIT; node bar.js) &
ruby foobar.rb
wait
```

Then, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will also kill those commands started asynchronously.